# Getting the values of table2.column1 into table1.column1

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

What i want is to get the values of all 'script' column from table 'item_db3' into 'script' column of table 'item_db2'

I tried this script

```
UPDATE item_db2 SET item_db2.script=item_db3.script
FROM item_db2
JOIN item_db3 on (item_db2.script=item_db3.script)
```

Answer (score 1):

interchange the `JOIN` and `SET` statement like

```
UPDATE item_db2 
JOIN item_db3 on item_db2.script = item_db3.script
SET item_db2.script = item_db3.script
```

** Not sure what you are trying to do but you are updating the column on which you are joining. That's bit strange

Comment: I've tried your code but nothing change. the value of item_db3.script ddnt go to item_db2.script.. 
** I just wanted to transfer the values of item_db3.script into item_db2.script

Comment: @Ranz, post your table structure for both tables in question. this doesn't looks a correct way

Answer (score 0):

Okay i've figured it out

```
UPDATE item_db2
SET item_db2.script=(SELECT item_db3.script
FROM item_db3
WHERE item_db3.id=item_db2.id);
```

Comment: well great that you have figured it but your post basically lacking information. it's working cause you have joined on a different column which is what should be done and that's what I exactly pointed in my answer

Comment: Yea i forgot to put the structure but both structure is the same. anyway thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE item_db2 
SET item_db2.script = item_db3.script
FROM item_db2 
JOIN item_db3
ON item_db2.script = item_db3.script
```

If the target table is currently empty then you should use an INSERT instead:

```
INSERT INTO item_db2 (script)
SELECT script FROM item_db3
```

Comment: Nope, you can't use `FROM` clause like that in `UPDATE` statement directly. Refer documentation